# Error while migrating from eclipse to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Hello I am new to android studio. I have a existing eclipse project, which runs on (2.3.3 android api 10) only.

When I migrate my existing eclipse project to android studio. I face below error.

```
Error:Unable to load class 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
You are using JDK version 'java version "1.7.0_75"'. Some versions of JDK 1.7 (e.g. 1.7.0_10) may cause class loading errors in Gradle.
Please update to a newer version (e.g. 1.7.0_67).
Open JDK Settings
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Here is my build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'android'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    }
android {
    compileSdkVersion 10
    buildToolsVersion "10"

     compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 10
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error says by itself doesn't it? Please update your JDK. This has nothing to do with your project, just your system.

Comment: I have already a newer java version 1.7.0_75. But it not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I just have to change my buildToolsVersion.

From

```
buildToolsVersion "10"
```

to

```
 buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
```

Now its works perfectly.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

please ensure your sdk is newer than jdk1.7.0_67.
 open your android studio preferences page for check.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: i feel sorry.your sdk version is newer than main(1.7.0.67). 1.7.0.67 is good for gradle in android studio,can you revert you jdk to this version?

Comment: btw,my gradle version is 2.4 .I manually download from here : https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-bin.zip